# HTML Searching on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one long page of content. If I want to create a search bar so that when the user searches something that exists somewhere on the single page, it redirects them to that part of the page (like it goes to the middle or the bottom of the page). Does this require any back-end like PHP or can I do this with just HTML?

Comment: You can do it entirely front-end with JavaScript ... though, the user *could* just tap `Ctrl + F` to pull up *Find* in their browser of choice.

Comment: Yeah I know Ctrl + F works too, but then I'm just curious and trying this out :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of `window.find()` in JavaScript
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Demo:

```js
function search(string){
window.find(string);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="type foo or bar" type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="search(document.getElementById('search').value)">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do would be some javascript

```
<input id="searchText"><button onclick="search()">Search</button>
<script>
function search() {
   var searchText = $("#searchBar").val();
   $(".searchText:contains('" + searchText + "')").css("background","#FF0");
}
</script>
<div class=".searchText">Some kind of text would go here</div>
```

Comment: `$("#searchBar").val();` should be `$("#searchText").val();` and `<div class=".searchText">` has a dot in the class name which should be removed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, was on here killing a little time, wrote this quick and stupidly didn't double check myself. My apologies